# SQL - how to remove whole row if one of the column in subquery return NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, select, subquery

I am stuck in 1 SQL query

```
SELECT u.*,

um2.meta_value as parent_user_id,
( select u.user_email FROM wp_users u WHERE u.ID = um2.meta_value ) AS parent_user_email

FROM

wp_users u 

JOIN wp_usermeta um2 ON u.ID = um2.user_id
AND um2.meta_key = 'parent_user_id'

GROUP BY
u.ID
```

This query return 4 row ( As shown in the screenshot )

I want a scenario like : If subquery return NULL , then the whole row will not be shown.
So in this example **"childthree"** should not be shown , as **"parent_user_email"** is NULL , so the whole 3rd row need to remove

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `join` instead:

```
SELECT u.*, um2.meta_value as parent_user_id,
       u2.user_email as parent_user_email
FROM wp_users u JOIN
     wp_usermeta um2
     ON u.ID = um2.user_id AND
        um2.meta_key = 'parent_user_id' JOIN
     wp_users u2
     ON u2.ID = um2.meta_value
GROUP BY u.ID;
```

Note:  This assumes that the email value itself is never `NULL`.  If that is possible, add `WHERE u2.user_email IS NOT NULL`.

Also, your query should fail because the `GROUP BY` columns are inconsistent with the `SELECT`.  However, logically it seems ok, because there is only one parent and user email per `user`.  However, I would include those columns in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Here the case is parent user is removed from "wp_user" table , but "parent_user_id" entry is still exist in "wp_usermeta" table